# Tomcat: keeping specific files when deploying a WAR file

Tags: tomcat, web-applications

Is there a way to tell tomcat to keep specific files under a exploded WAR file's directory?

let's say I have the following folder that I've created after the WAR has been deployed:

```
/webapps/myApp/uploads
```

Everytime I deploy the WAR it is deleted. Is there a way to keep this directory and its files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Tomcat 6.0 deployment howto](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html), the exploded webapp *"is removed, and the .WAR is expanded again"*. So the whole `/webapps/myApp/` directory gets deleted upon deployment. There is no way to keep the files in it.

If you want to keep the uploaded files, you should define a directory outside your webapp dir, and use that from within the web application.